# Comparison between arrays and objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, lodash, javascript-objects

I need to compare two array/objects but I am not able to figure out how since they are coming from two different sources and have different formats.

```
oldData = [{Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"},{Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"}]


newData = [[Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"],[Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"]]
```

I tried comparing using these methods

```
(JSON.stringify(oldData) == JSON.stringify(newData))
(_.isEqual(oldData, newData))
```

I also tried,

```
 _.forEach(newData, function (element: any, i: number) {
      dataObj.push(newData);
  });
```

But nothing is working for me. Any help here would be appreciated.
Added: How can I convert newData to valid data?
Thanks.

Comment: `newData` is invalid ,

Comment: What do you mean when you say "two different formats"? `newData` is definitely not valid.

Comment: How can I convert newData to valid data?

Answer (score 0):

Only possible if newData is a string

```js
const oldData = [{Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"},{Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"}]


const newDataString = `[[Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"],[Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"]]`

const newDataR = JSON.parse(newDataString
  .replace('[[','[{')
  .replace(']]','}]')
  .replace('],[','},{')  
  .replace(/(\w+): /g,'"$1":')
);  
  
console.log(newDataR)
console.log(JSON.stringify(oldData) === JSON.stringify(newDataR))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform both to string and use regex to replace '{' and '}' with '[' and ']'.

```js
let oldData = '[{Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"},{Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"}]'


let newData = '[[Row_id: "32F993F", Parameter_Type: "String", UOM: "", rowId: "1"],[Row_id: "88898897-988D-4168-B662-2DECEA0E72BD", Parameter: "id", Parameter_Type: "Integer", UOM: "", rowId: "2"]]'


oldData = oldData.replace(/[{]/g, '[');
oldData = oldData.replace(/[}]/g, ']');

console.log(oldData === newData);
```